# Bootstrap 4 stack image on image

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm currently working on a website using Bootstrap 4. I have a div with an image of someone holding an iPad inside it. The iPad screen is transparent, so my idea was to put a image in that section or a video.

I'm not a css expert, but is it possible to put the image behind the tablet with z-index?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <img id="wallpaper" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" width="35%" class="mx-auto d-block">
        <img id="tablet" src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/58fb507e4582f15b95b26d4d.png" width="60%" class="mx-auto d-block">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can achieve this effect by [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) your elements. You don't need the `z-index` here, as your elements are already in the right order. Keep in mind, that the image has to fit into the tablets frame. This is currently not the case.

Here is a working example:

```css
#wallpaper,
#tablet {
  position: absolute;
}

#wallpaper {
  width: 200px;
  top: 70px;
  left: 110px;
}

#tablet {
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <img id="wallpaper" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="mx-auto d-block">
    <img id="tablet" src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/58fb507e4582f15b95b26d4d.png" class="mx-auto d-block">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://%3Cscript%20async%20src=%22//jsfiddle.net/bentlynixon/xg7tb6fL/2/embed/%22%3E%3C/script%3E) Explains how to stack images with the help of z-index.

Answer (score 0):

You have to play around with the responsiveness - but the idea could be the following :

```css
.tabletWrapper {
  position:relative;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:600px;
}

#wallpaper, #tablet {
  position:absolute;
}

#tablet {
  left:0;
  right:0;
  width:65%;
}

#wallpaper {
  left:0; 
  right:11px;
  width:33%;
  top:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="tabletWrapper">
    <img id="wallpaper" src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" class="mx-auto d-block">
    <img id="tablet" src="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/58fb507e4582f15b95b26d4d.png" class="mx-auto d-block">
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```